# Running `node index.js` from command line works but when I use the start script in my package.json I get an EADDRINUSE /usr/bin/local/node error

Tags: node.js, heroku, server, yarnpkg

I can run `node index.js` from the directly from the command line but when I run the start script that has the same command I get an error.

Here is the relative server info:

```
const PORT = process.env.NODE || 3000

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on ${PORT}`))
```

Here is the package.json script:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
},
```

Here is the terminal output ran from the project root running it without the script:

```
 > node index.js
 Server running on port 3000
```

Here is the terminal output running it with the script:

```
>yarn start
yarn run v1.10.1
$ node index.js
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE /usr/local/bin/node
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1343:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1401:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1496:5)
    at Function.listen (/Users/mmelv/Workspace/Projects/Reportably/server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mmelv/Workspace/Projects/Reportably/server/index.js:29:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

This has boggled me for hours. I've tried `sudo killall node`, `lsof -i tcp:3000` returns nothing. I've reinstalled and upgraded node.

Also, I get the same error when I try to deploy it to Heroku:

```
2018-10-07T15:47:56.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-10-07T15:47:58.569471+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-10-07T15:48:01.927982+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-07T15:48:01.928007+00:00 app[web.1]: > server@1.0.0 start /app
2018-10-07T15:48:01.928009+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2018-10-07T15:48:01.928010+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-07T15:48:02.936929+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:183
2018-10-07T15:48:02.936974+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2018-10-07T15:48:02.936976+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-10-07T15:48:02.936977+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-07T15:48:02.936979+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: listen EADDRINUSE /app/.heroku/node/bin/node
2018-10-07T15:48:02.936981+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
2018-10-07T15:48:02.936982+00:00 app[web.1]: at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
2018-10-07T15:48:02.936984+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1338:19)
2018-10-07T15:48:02.936985+00:00 app[web.1]: at listenInCluster (net.js:1396:12)
2018-10-07T15:48:02.936987+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server.listen (net.js:1491:5)
2018-10-07T15:48:02.936989+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.listen (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
2018-10-07T15:48:02.936990+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:29:5)
2018-10-07T15:48:02.936992+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
2018-10-07T15:48:02.936993+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
2018-10-07T15:48:02.936995+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
2018-10-07T15:48:02.936996+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
2018-10-07T15:48:02.936998+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
2018-10-07T15:48:02.936999+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
2018-10-07T15:48:02.937001+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
2018-10-07T15:48:02.937003+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
2018-10-07T15:48:03.081497+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-10-07T15:48:03.082095+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2018-10-07T15:48:03.083978+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! server@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
2018-10-07T15:48:03.088003+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2018-10-07T15:48:03.088362+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2018-10-07T15:48:03.088616+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 start script.
2018-10-07T15:48:03.088965+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I'm not sure what else to do. Why can I run `node index.js` but not the start script that does the same thing?

Comment: Maybe an issue of scope? Try  adding a `console.log(PORT)` just above your `app.listen` and see if maybe it's different than you expected.

Comment: Try a different port. If it doesn't fail then you know it is a problem with this port(maybe something still running there). If it fails to start again then you can start to look at your code/script, maybe something weird happens.

Comment: OMG, do you guys see it? I had `process.env.NODE` and not `process.env.PORT`

Comment: I wanna die now lol

Comment: fail ..........

Answer (score 0):

I had to change `process.env.NODE` to `process.env.PORT`...
I know, I know...